# how to use request.querystring properly

Tags: vb.net

In my page URL, there is a property taskgrpid - In my code I would like to use the value as an integer. Listed below is the URL from the page and here is my request for the string. Please tell me why I am always getting a value of 0 for x. Thank you

```
http://localhost:2098/observations/ViewObservation.aspx?taskgrpid=55&taskgrpcategory=11&ptaskgrpid=390&ptaskgrpcategory=10

dim x as integer = request.querystring("taskgrpid")
```

update, for some reason this works at page load, but not in any other functions that i have called, any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have taskgrpid=55 and taskgrpid=390 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
dim x as integer = request.querystring("taskgrpid")
```

to:

```
dim x as integer = CInt(request.querystring("taskgrpid"))
```